# React - Code won't work in Render or ComponentDidMount

Tags: reactjs

So I have some code that attempts to put a list of s containing quiz questions & answers into a variable in state. Part of those divs also checks for other state elements (such as selected).

```
    render() {

        for (const [index, value] of this.props.quiz.entries()) {
            this.state.quizItems.push(
                <div className="questions">
                    {value.answers.map((answers, index) => (<h3 key={index}
                                                                onClick={() => this.selectItem(index)}
                                                                className={this.state.selected === index ? 'selected btn' : 'btn'}>{answers}</h3>))
                    }
                </div>)
        }
        return (
            <div className="modal-window ">
                {this.state.quizItems[this.state.currentQuizItem]}
            </div>
        )
    };
```

However my problem is I don't know where to put this in a component - I can't keep it in the render() method as above, as you can't update state from there else you get an error about recursive state updates.

So I try and put it in ComponentDidMount() but then the checking of state.selected doesn't work as that part of the lifecycle doesn't get called on a state update.

Where can i move the above code so that the state can be updated with the divs at the start of the component, while allowing the checking of state?

Comment: Why do you need to store this stuff in state at all? Can't you render what you need from the `quiz` prop combined with `currentQuizItem` from state?

Comment: Also, the short & direct answer to your question is that you can't put this code anywhere. `this.state.quizItems.push` directly mutates state, which is not allowed in React. You'll need to determine what you need, then have a method (NOT in render) call setState for you instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can encapsulate the logic somewhere in the component maybe as a method and then call that method when you need to do the render:

```
class ... {

  // Other methods...

  renderCurrentQuizItem() {
    const quizEntries = this.props.quiz.entries();
    const currentQuizEntry = quizEntries[this.state.currentQuizItem];
    const [_, value] = currentQuizEntry;
    return (
      <div className="questions">
        {value.answers.map((answers, index) => (<h3 key={index}
          onClick={() => this.selectItem(index)}
          className={this.state.selected === index ? 'selected btn' : 'btn'}>{answers}</h3>))
        }
      </div>);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="modal-window ">
        {this.renderCurrentQuizItem()}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Note that instead of processing all the quiz entries(mapping them into divs) and then selecting just one of them to render as you did in the render method you posted, the `renderCurrentQuizItem` method processes just one of the quiz entries that needs to be rendered(as identified by `this.state.currentQuizItem`)and I think that's cleaner. You can still do it the other way though, depending on the way you need it to work.